# How can I reduce the amount of C# code used in this program?

Tags: c#

So I'm trying to write a simple program for practicing purposes, I got this to work the way I want it but I still feel like I can reduce the amount of code used, any suggestions?

Thanks, in advance!

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string playerAnswer = Console.ReadLine();
            string potReward = "";
            string trueReward = calculateReward(playerAnswer, potReward);

            Console.WriteLine("Congratulations, you won {0}! ", trueReward);

        }

        private static string calculateReward(string answer, string reward)
        {
            if (answer == "1")
            {
                reward = "a cat";
            }
            else if (answer == "2")
            {
                reward = "power to rival Chuck Norris";
            }
            else if (answer == "3")
            {
                reward = "a burger";
            }
            else
            {
                reward = "nothing";
            }

            return reward;
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I get the feeling this is your graded homework, not just practice, in any case here is some help.

There are plenty of excellent tutorials for free online, here is one example that assumes no previous coding or C# experience.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/intro-to-csharp/

Some starting points might be to look at:

**switch statements**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/switch

```
      int caseSwitch = 1;

      switch (caseSwitch)
      {
          case 1:
              Console.WriteLine("Case 1");
              break;
          case 2:
              Console.WriteLine("Case 2");
              break;
          default:
              Console.WriteLine("Default case");
              break;
      }
```

**multiple variable assignment**

https://www.dotnetperls.com/multiple-local-variable (*general C-style guides can often apply too, though stick to C# if unsure at all*)

`string s = "dot", a = "net", m = "perls";`

And **are all your variables actually being used/useful?**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/passing-value-type-parameters

> A value-type variable contains its data directly as opposed to a reference-type variable, which contains a reference to its data. Passing a value-type variable to a method by value means passing a copy of the variable to the method. Any changes to the parameter that take place inside the method have no affect on the original data stored in the argument variable. If you want the called method to change the value of the argument, you must pass it by reference, using the ref or out keyword. You may also use the in keyword to pass a value parameter by reference to avoid the copy while guaranteeing that the value will not be changed. For simplicity, the following examples use ref.

Also, if its a private function, see if actually needing to be separate, though likely it will be if part of larger solution/project.

Ive deliberately not updated your sample code, very simple to do given examples and the more you type it out yourself the more you get used to the language.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: This helped solve it, thank you.

I'm so inexperienced that I'm failing a Homework-level program.

Comment: @lilac - dont forget the last **bold** point too, hint hint ;)

Comment: I am actually not sure, I tried without the `reward` string, but couldn't get it to work properly.

Comment: @lilac - Take a look at your variables and params, trace thier lifecycle and decide what is or isnt needed to be passed around. Your exercise is very simple, everything is just being passed by value (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/passing-value-type-parameters) That guide assumes some extra knowledge around reference variables and such, but the key is that they are VALUE type params, nothing else. 

Read whaterver your teacher/course gave you, answer is right there and will help you SO much more later down track to figure it out yourself

Comment: @lilac - ive made an edit to my answer, last hint ;)

Comment: Thank you so much, I managed to get it working without the `reward` parameter, but I'm a bit confused as to when I should use params in the first place, they're supposed to allow you to add variables from outside the method body, correct?

and I will definitely check out more courses asap.

Comment: @lilac - params are either Pointers/References (aka physical address of a variable, allowing it to ALSO be updated in the called function, without needing it to be returned - very useful if updating multiple variables) OR value type params (for copying in a value, to be used inside the function). You 'can' ALSO return the pointer/reference type param, no real need for it in 99.9% of time. **In your case** its passing in a copy, ignoring it (re-assigning/replacing with '=', instead of '+=' or similar) and returning the NEW value. So you can rewrite it with ref variable + no return, or no param.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the ternary operator for filter:

```
    private static string calculateReward(string answer, string reward)
    {
        reward = answer == "1" ? "a cat" : answer == "2" ? "power to rival Chuck Norris" : answer == "3" ? "a burger" : "nothing";
        return reward;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A switch-case statement is the best way to go on this one.

```
switch(answer) 
{
     case 1:
         reward = "A cat."; 
         break;
     case 2: 
         reward = "Power to rival Chuck Norris."; 
         break;
     case 3: 
         reward = "A burger"; 
         break;
     default: 
         reward = "Nothing"; 
         break;
}
```

Comment: Nice answer, maybe not give copy/paste answers to people showing zero effort and obviously asking us to their homework lol :)